# Making the whole width of the label clickable and responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, label

So, I have a gallery with filters. I need the filters (done as labels) to be clickable as is the first filter "All" at the moment.  The problem is, as you can see when you resize the window, that the label is not responsive. Padding is done in rems, but the div.filters is not containing the label padding necessary for clickability inside of itself. How can that be achieved that when you resize the window that the label padding is contained inside the red borders?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --turquoise: rgb(56, 184, 201);
  --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --poppyred: rgb(199, 74, 82);
}

ol,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* 5. FILTERS */

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.filters {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.filter-item {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: .3rem;
  color: var(--white);
}

.filter-item label {
  text-align: center;
  background: var(--turquoise);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filter-item label:hover {
  background: var(--poppyred);
}

[value="all"]:checked~.grid-gallery [data-category] {
  display: block;
}

[value="branding"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="branding"]),
[value="graphical"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="graphical"]),
[value="interior"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="interior"]),
[value="illustrations"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="illustrations"]),
[value="arts"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="arts"]) {
  display: none;
}


/* Change color on click */

[value="all"]:checked~.filters [for="all"],
[value="branding"]:checked~.filters [for="branding"],
[value="graphical"]:checked~.filters [for="graphical"],
[value="interior"]:checked~.filters [for="interior"],
[value="illustrations"]:checked~.filters [for="illustrations"],
[value="arts"]:checked~.filters [for="arts"] {
  background: var(--poppyred);
}


/* 6. GALLERY */

.grid-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.photo img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/*LABEL PADDING*/

.filter-items .filter-item:nth-child(1) label {
  padding: 0 57.8em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Filters -->
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="all" value="all" checked>
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="branding" value="branding">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="graphical" value="graphical">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="interior" value="interior">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="illustrations" value="illustrations">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="arts" value="arts">

<div class="filters">
  <ol class="filter-items">
    <li class="filter-item"><label for="all">All</label></li>
    <li class="filter-item"><label for="branding">Branding</label></li>
    <li class="filter-item"><label for="graphical">Graphical Design</label></li>
    <li class="filter-item"><label for="interior">Interior Design</label></li>
    <li class="filter-item"><label for="illustrations">Illustrations</label></li>
    <li class="filter-item"><label for="arts">Arts</label></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="grid-gallery">

  <div class="photo" data-category="branding">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="branding">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="graphical">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="arts">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="arts">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="interior">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="graphical">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="branding">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="illustrations">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="interior">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's the Codepen:
[Codepen Gallery with filters](https://codepen.io/abudimir/pen/OJXJrMK?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a strange padding making the "All" wide. I would remove that and use `display: block;` on the labels. In my example below I made a few other changes removing the `<div class="filter"></div>` as you don't need that. Moved the margin and border to the `<ol>` itself.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --turquoise: rgb(56, 184, 201);
  --white: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  --poppyred: rgb(199, 74, 82);
}

ol,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* 5. FILTERS */

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.filter-items {
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.filter-item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: .3rem;
  color: var(--white);
}

.filter-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.filter-item label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: var(--turquoise);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filter-item label:hover {
  background: var(--poppyred);
}

[value="all"]:checked~.grid-gallery [data-category] {
  display: block;
}

[value="branding"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="branding"]),
[value="graphical"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="graphical"]),
[value="interior"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="interior"]),
[value="illustrations"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="illustrations"]),
[value="arts"]:checked~.grid-gallery .photo:not([data-category~="arts"]) {
  display: none;
}


/* Change color on click */

[value="all"]:checked~.filter-items [for="all"],
[value="branding"]:checked~.filter-items [for="branding"],
[value="graphical"]:checked~.filter-items [for="graphical"],
[value="interior"]:checked~.filter-items [for="interior"],
[value="illustrations"]:checked~.filter-items [for="illustrations"],
[value="arts"]:checked~.filter-items [for="arts"] {
  background: var(--poppyred);
}


/* 6. GALLERY */

.grid-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.photo img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


/*LABEL PADDING

.filter-items .filter-item:nth-child(1) label {
  padding: 0 57.8em;
}
*/
```

```html
<!-- Filters -->
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="all" value="all" checked>
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="branding" value="branding">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="graphical" value="graphical">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="interior" value="interior">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="illustrations" value="illustrations">
<input type="radio" name="categories" id="arts" value="arts">

<ol class="filter-items">
  <li class="filter-item"><label for="all">All</label></li>
  <li class="filter-item"><label for="branding">Branding</label></li>
  <li class="filter-item"><label for="graphical">Graphical Design</label></li>
  <li class="filter-item"><label for="interior">Interior Design</label></li>
  <li class="filter-item"><label for="illustrations">Illustrations</label></li>
  <li class="filter-item"><label for="arts">Arts</label></li>
</ol>

<!-- Gallery -->
<div class="grid-gallery">

  <div class="photo" data-category="branding">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="branding">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="graphical">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="arts">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="arts">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="interior">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="graphical">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="branding">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="illustrations">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/529/200/200.jpg?hmac=LiB-rmOEJ-iPyye6kU2u9mmHGs_o7w5wrCHbzlNX5b0" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="photo" data-category="interior">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/861/200/200.jpg?hmac=UJSK-tjn1gjzSmwHWZhjpaGahNSBDQWpMoNvg8Bxy8k" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hvala, Dejane!
That's it. I knew I was missing something. Accepted your answer since you were the first. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Add this class

```
.filter-items {
    width: 100%;
 }
```

And change this class

```
.filter-item label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: var(--turquoise);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```